# Codeigniter 3 blogging application bug: post slug updates even if there are no changes to the post's title

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a basic blog application with **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and **Bootstrap 4**.

For this application, the posts are *uniquely identified by slug* and displayed to the viewers.

I have created a mechanism that *prevents duplicate slugs* in case there are duplicate post titles, by adding numbers to the slugs. This mechanism is included in both the `create()` and `update()` methods of the Posts controller.

Inside the `update()` method this mechanism functions imperfectly: the post slug updates even if there are no changes to the post's title (*my-post-title* becomes *my-post-title-1* if the "Update" button is pressed even id there is no duplicate of the post's title).

Here is the `create()` method in the **Posts** controller. There are no problems with it:

```
 public function create() {

    // Only logged in users can create posts
    if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
        redirect('login');
    }

    $data = $this->get_data();
    $data['tagline'] = "Add New Post";

    if ($data['categories']) {
        foreach ($data['categories'] as &$category) {
            $category->posts_count = $this->Posts_model->count_posts_in_category($category->id);
        }
    }

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Short description', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('dashboard/create-post');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    } else {
        // Create slug (from title)
        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);
        $slugcount = $this->Posts_model->slug_count($slug);
        if ($slugcount > 0) {
            $slug = $slug."-".$slugcount;
        }

        // Upload image
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/posts';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
            $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $post_image = 'default.jpg';
        } else {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        }

        $this->Posts_model->create_post($post_image, $slug);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('post_created', 'Your post has been created');
        redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Here is the `update()` method in the **Posts** controller:

```
public function update() {
    // Form data validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Short description', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required',  array('required' => 'The %s field can not be empty'));
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');

    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    // Update slug (from title)
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);
        $slugcount = $this->Posts_model->slug_count($slug);
        if ($slugcount > 0) {
            $slug = $slug."-".$slugcount;
        }
    } else {
        $slug = $this->input->post('slug');
    }

    // Upload image
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/posts';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (isset($_FILES['userfile']['name']) && $_FILES['userfile']['name'] != null) {
        // Use name field in do_upload method
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
            $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        } else {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $post_image = $data[ 'raw_name'].$data[ 'file_ext'];
        }
    }
    else {
        $post_image = $this->input->post('postimage');
    }

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $this->Posts_model->update_post($id, $post_image, $slug);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('post_updated', 'Your post has been updated');
        redirect('/' . $slug);
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->run();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', validation_errors());
        redirect('/dashboard/posts/edit/' . $slug);
    }
}
```

In the **Posts_model** model I have:

```
// Count the slugs in the posts table
public function slug_count($slug){
    $this->db->select('count(*) as slugcount');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->where('slug', $slug);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row(0)->slugcount;
}

// Update post
public function update_post($id, $post_image, $slug) {
    $data = [
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'slug' => $slug,
        'description' => $this->input->post('desc'),
        'content' => $this->input->post('body'),
        'post_image' => $post_image,
        'cat_id' => $this->input->post('category'),
        'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ];

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    return $this->db->update('posts', $data);
}
```

How shall I change the code above so that the bug described above is fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it's counting itself as well and will always more than 1 if updating so you need to add another where statement (and pass the 'id' param as well)

```
$this->db->where('id !=', $id);
```

To the 'slug_count' func after

```
$this->db->where('slug', $slug);
```

So it won't count itself

To summarize:
In `create()` method change to this:

`$slugcount = $this->Posts_model->slug_count($slug, null);`

In `update()` method change to this:

`$slugcount = $this->Posts_model->slug_count($slug, $id);`

And here's the slug_count:

```
// Count the slugs in the posts table
public function slug_count($slug, $id){
    $this->db->select('count(*) as slugcount');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->where('slug', $slug);
    // if its an update
    if ($id != null) {
        $this->db->where('id !=', $id);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row(0)->slugcount;
}
```

Comment: The function`slug_count($slug)` is also used in the `create()` method of the Posts controller. Will it be affected?

Comment: Yes. You need to pass the `id` var as well to the `slug_count` and check wether it is a new post or not. I'm guessing if it's new the id the var will be `null` so wrap the second where in an `if ($id != null) $this->db->where('id !=', $id);`

Answer (score 1):

```
// Update post
public function update_post($id, $post_image, $slug) {
    $data = [
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'slug' => $slug,
        'description' => $this->input->post('desc'),
        'content' => $this->input->post('body'),
        'post_image' => $post_image,
        'cat_id' => $this->input->post('category'),
        'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ];

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('title');

    $count_row = $query->num_rows();

    if ($count_row > 0) {

        return FALSE; 
     } else {

        return $this->db->update('posts', $data); 
     }

}
```

Comment: I already have a slug count: `$slugcount = $this->Posts_model->slug_count($slug);`.